# Is there a tree control for the iphone?

Tags: iphone, treecontrol

Is there a Tree control available for the iphone?

I need to represent a tree with sub nodes in a tree, how can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: If you mean a built in data structure, I think the answer is no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, the best solution for my problem will be a BreadCrumbs control. I am looking for a ready solution of breadcrumbs, but if there isn't, it is not a big deal to write it.

Answer (score 7):

No tree widget by default. It's basically not there because you shouldn't really need one and most cases it should probably be avoided.

A table navigation controller is the most common way to navigate down nodes in a hierarchy/tree usually.

It's hard to fit a tree like control we have on our desktops in the touch world where you have huge fingers (so huge nodes) and with the nodes offset to show depth, there isn't much space left over. Adding it to the iOS environment would create a weird UX flow so I would probably rethink my design flow if I think I need one.

If you need to fake it, you can use a table view and offset the left side of each subitem with some padding to show depth.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH3-SW1

Comment: I am looking for a control, a third party control. Not a view or the navigation.

Answer (score 1):

See this help

Rolling your own iPhone treeview control

part 1 : http://dotnet.kapenilattex.com/?p=566, part 2 and part 3 are in the pages : 585 and 633
part 4 : http://dotnet.kapenilattex.com/?p=648&cpage=1#comment-59842

Answer (score 0):

I would use a UITableView and expand and collapse items further down the tree. You can set an indentation level for each UITableViewCell as it is displayed, depending on its position in the tree. You would need to keep track of which items in the tree are expanded/visible in order to always provide the tree with the correct data.

I just did just that for a project. Unfortunately I am not at liberty to share the full code. But it should not be terribly hard to write.

Let us know if you find an out-of-the-box solution.

Answer (score -2):

OK, I did it.

I added a WebView and I am adding to it the crumb list. The design is similar to the Apple's official site.

When a user clikcs on the link, I call the popToViewController function and I am there.

This prevent the user from clicking Back and Back.

Hope this will help somebody.